# How to encode file lua and resource files

Tags: android

[image]

I am trying to decrypt luas files it use cocos2dx but its encrypted maybe aes encryption.
With frida i can extract most lua files but not all.
And with ida64 i cant find the key.

Comment: As you are already using Frida, have you tried to identify the cryptographic functions and hook them to get the key and the crypto-/ and matching plaintext?

Comment: problem is ida64 is soo slow to debug with android device samsung s7
and with frida it dont trigger and xxtea and aes dont trigger so i must use ida64 to debug. And some times and it crash and wow i most restart from null

Comment: have someone a way how to decrypt aes encryptions?

Comment: You don't need Ida to debug. Just use IDA to identify the crypto functions and then write the frida code to hook them.

Comment: Mhh when i find the right crypto functions but know i found that some files have the same sign

Here when you want to debug decompile... self 
http://bit.ly/3E3VACp
PirateArena the newest version  for 64bit and a dead game (the servers are live but discord is dead)
here my discord when you want to talk Madara981#0086

Comment: ida64 open `\lib\arm64-v8a\libcocos2dlua.so` in function `AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching`. You can see `IV` and `KEY` for `AES CBC mode` algorithm.

[image](https://imgur.com/a/UuvSFAq)

**IV**: `08 C6 0B 9E 20 74 7B A1 8F 7E FA 81 12 BB 36 0C`

**KEY**: `DC 6A D9 83 4A 8B AF 68 0C CB 2C 22 B1 FE 3B 22 03 97 AB E3 3D 2F 56 1E 61 CF EA A9 96 A6 94 4D`